# Polar coordinates: how to plot straight line at $n$ degrees?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

What equation represents a straight line at $n$ degrees/radians in polar coordinate system?

I know in Cartesian coordinates:
$y = \sin\frac{2\pi}{3}x +0$

Polar conversion:
$x = r \cos\rho$ and $y = r \sin\rho$

So I substitue:
$0 = \sin \frac{2\pi}{3}x - y$

$0 = \sin \frac{2\pi}{3} r \cos \theta - r \sin \theta$

$0 = r(\sin \frac{2\pi}{3} \cos \theta - \sin \theta)$

So $r$ is zero???

Comment: There are lots of such lines. Be specific. And tell us what you’ve tried.

Comment: Remember that you can write down an equation in rectangular coordinates (in terms of $x$ and $y$), then make the substitutions $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$ and possibly simplify the result. Try this and edit your post to include your work.

Comment: I know in Cartesian coordinates $y = \sin\frac{2\pi}{3}x$ and $x = r cos(\theta)$ and $y = r sin(\theta)$

Comment: You can use LaTeX markup like this: `$x = r\cos\theta$` and `$\frac{2\pi}{3}$` for $x = r\cos\theta$ and $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, etc. [More here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @TedShifrin I updated the post with what I tried

Comment: Does your line go through the origin?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin in the Cartesian graph it does, however I do not care if it does in the Polar

Comment: I'm trying to get a straight line on a polar graph at 120 degrees

Comment: The equation of a line through the origin in cartesian coordinates is $y=mx$ with $m$ the slope. The slope is not the sine.

Comment: First, your $\sin(2\pi/3)$ coefficient is incorrect. No, *either* $r=0$ or $\tan\theta = \dots$.

Answer (score 1):

A polar equation is given using $r$ (the radius) and $\theta$ (the angle), just like a cartesian equation is given using $x$ and $y$.

The straight line through the origin making an angle $\alpha$ with the positive $x$-axis would then simply be given by the equation
$$\theta=\alpha.$$
This equation leaves $r$ free to take any (positive, negative, or zero) value, so it corresponds to all points on that line. For $\alpha=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ radians (120 degrees), the equation would be
$$\theta=\frac{2\pi}{3}.$$

You can also see this from the equations of the cartesian line. The line would be
$$\begin{align*}
 y &= \frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos\alpha}x\\
(\cos\alpha)y &= (\sin\alpha)x\\
(\cos\alpha)r\sin\theta &= (\sin\alpha)r\cos\theta.
\end{align*}$$
The value of $r$ is irrelevant, so we can cancel (when $r=0$ we get the same point regardless of the value of $\theta$). This leaves
$$\tan\theta = \tan\alpha,$$
which gives $\theta=\alpha+n\pi$ for an arbitrary integer $n$.
Now simply note that $\theta=\alpha+n\pi$ for any integer $n$ describes the same line.

Comment: Thanks this works in Grapher, do you know given my post why I couldn't solve for $r$?

Comment: @Nick Because you set up the equation wrong. The equation is $y=mx$ where $m$ is the **slope**. The slope is the tangent of the angle, not the sine. That's what I wrote.

Comment: Also for the line $by = \pm ax$, the corresponding polar equation would be $\theta = \arctan (\pm b/a)$.